# EpubReader.Cross is not working

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to use [EpubReader.Cross](https://github.com/g0rdan/EpubReader.Cross) plugin to read epub file. I am loading the file as like below and i am getting the below exception. Please suggest your options to fix the issue.

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(mobileFileName, FileMode.Open);
EpubBook epubBook = EpubReader.ReadBook(stream);
```

**Exception**:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory record could not be found.
at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory () [0x0002c] in <755caed138d141c5b26f18fea3c29594>:0
at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init (System.IO.Stream stream, System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode mode, System.Boolean leaveOpen) [0x001c8] in <755caed138d141c5b26f18fea3c29594>:0
at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream, System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode mode, System.Boolean leaveOpen, System.Text.Encoding entryNameEncoding) [0x0001c] in <755caed138d141c5b26f18fea3c29594>:0
at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <755caed138d141c5b26f18fea3c29594>:0
at VersFx.Formats.Text.Epub.EpubReader+d__1.MoveNext () [0x0001f] in :0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0
at VersFx.Formats.Text.Epub.EpubReader+d__3.MoveNext () [0x00081] in :0
```